# How can i send the keys ` and ´ with Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to send the Keys ` and ´ to an Input-Element with the sendKeys method. But the characters are not shown in the input.

The documentation says nothing about these keys.
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Keys.htm

```
WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.id("UserName"));

element.SendKeys("´ `");
```

Comment: I was able to send the characters, are you doing something different?

Can you also try get the input value from developer tools in browser

Comment: The input value do not include these chars either. Maybe it is because my input is customized.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to desktop browsers the easiest is to go for [driver.ExecuteScript()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm) method in order to [set the `<input>` element value by means of JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Reference code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value=\"´ `\";", element);
```

Be aware that the approach might not work for [Appium](http://appium.io) device automation as [certain mobile platforms/browsers cannot execute JavaScript like desktop browsers do](https://experitest.com/appium/appium-testing-ios9-10/).